# If I lose/drop the master sword, how can I get it back?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

If you lose the master sword by unrecoverable means. Let's say to dropped it down a cliff with no bottom. How can you get it back?

Comment: How do you plan on dropping it?  To my knowledge you can't even do that

Comment: I ask before I do something dumb. Is there really no way to be separated of the master sword? When I get hit by electric attacks I often drop sword/shield. Or if I would press ZR to throw the master sword, would that not work? I got it yesterday and havent tried yet to throw it away. It's stuck to my pockets with crazy glue?

Comment: @Fredy31 ZR doesn't allow you to throw the Master Sword. If you're at full health, it fires a sword beam though. As for the electricity thing, I'll give a test later today and get back to you.

Comment: Also, well, I'm getting destroyed by downvotes for some reason. Can a down voter explain to me what is wrong here? There is also no close votes, so I can't go and look why this is getting downvoted.

Comment: Because the question is based on a false premise that can't happen.

Comment: The downvotes are probably because you didn't bother checking yourself if you can even do what you're asking. Even if you could lose Master Sword, you could always reload from a save, right? Plus, from a story standpoint, it doesn't make much sense for Link to lose the Master Sword. There are no close votes because the question isn't off-topic... but it's not a good question either.

Comment: Story wise maybe, but mechanics wise it's a little dumb that you can drop everything and lose weapons when shocked, but the master sword is immune to all that.

Comment: Why the down votes? What if someone doesn't even own the game? How could one try for oneself??

Comment: I lost it at the camels boss due to electricity shock and since then I have not been able to retrieve it. I got the message that it has been restored and hoped that it would be at its original place again but it was not. Maybe a bug?!

Comment: Check your swords inventory, should be 1st slot. If you dont have it, it wasn't the master sword.

Comment: Shame to the downvoters.  This is a legit question that one can and should ask when they get something very very valuable in a game.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot drop the Master Sword, nor can you throw it away. Once you get it, you won't be able to lose it. Even electricity will not make you drop the Master Sword.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. By no means in the game is it possible to drop the Master Sword. Not to worry.

Comment: This says the same thing as the accepted answer

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot see the other answers. I'm using my phone and only see the questions and my answer as I type. I apologize for the redundancy.

Comment: Are you using the app? You should still have to scroll by the excusing answers before reaching add an answer button

Comment: @Angz: no, this one also advise us not worry. Good advise.