# How does the Master Sword differ from other swords in the game?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I just got the Master Sword, and I'd like to know how it EXACTLY works. Can anyone tell me?

Comment: Point it at things and they go away?  Just kidding, I don't even have the game... Yet.

Comment: @Wondercricket It's not really a dupe of that question specifically, since it's asking about more than just the durability. That said, this info is easy enough to find online, not to mention it's been discussed on this site in a couple of places. Clearly no research was done before asking this question.  But that makes it a candidate for downvoting, not closure.

Comment: @MageXy Hence my edit. I briefly forgot about the beams it shoot, so the did covered 2 out of 3 of your points

Answer (score 5):

The Master Sword is just like any other broadsword as far as attack range, attack speed, and fighting style are concerned. It does have a few differences though.

- [It never "breaks"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/302967/145980) - that is, it never disappears from your inventory once you own it. However, just like any other weapon, it does have durability. Once the durability runs out, it will be unequippable until it "recharges", which takes 10 minutes.
- [You cannot throw it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/303318/145980). Instead, you will perform a directed sword slash in the direction you are facing (kind of like using a wand or rod). If you are at full health, this slashing attack will release an energy beam which travels in a straight line (an homage to the classic Master Sword attack from other Zelda games).
- [The Master Sword's base attack power](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/309339/145980) is 30. If you are in the vicinity of Malice (specifically: Guardians, Divine Beasts, Hyrule Castle, or Ganon himself), this power will be upgraded to 60. In addition, the blade is much more durable and lasts longer while in this upgraded state.

Comment: Basically, it's "Unique". I doubt the dev's would want the player to be able to throw the master sword at a Bokoblin, only to have it fall off a cliff and be lost forever

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that the attack power of 30 can be upgraded to 40, 50, or 60 with the trial of the sword.